# Size of HDFS database does not make sense

Tags: hive, hdfs

I am given these usage statistics on my HDFS folder allocated to my project.

```
hdfs dfs -df -h hdfs://hp3/data/test_data.db

Filesystem   Size   Used  Available  Use%
hdfs://hp3  6.1 P  5.1 P      1.0 P   83%
```

What does the 'P' stand for? It cannot be petabytes because I know the data I have uploaded and it is ~ 10 GB.

Answer (score 0):

Disk usage command is

```
 hdfs dfs -du -s -h hdfs://hp3/data/test_data.db
```

Also count can be used:

```
hadoop fs -count -v -h hdfs://hp3/data/test_data.db
```

Command you used if for free space:

`-df` command displays free space